# Using jQuery to Insert Value Inside of Element, Not After

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using jQuery to calculate the file size of linked documents, using the snippet below. The code inserts the information wrapped in a span element after the a element. I'd like to insert it in the value of the a element instead. Is this possible?

Thanks!

js (source: http://jshidell.com/2010/09/20/show-document-file-size-using-jquery/)

```
<script>
  function hdrDetails(i, elm, cl) {
    cl = cl/1024;  //divide content-length by 1024 (KB)
    var sz = cl>1024?"MB":"KB";  //if cl is still big, set to MB
    cl = cl>1024?cl/1024:cl;  //if cl is still big, divide again
    var len = $(elm).eq(i).text().length;  //check the link's text length
    if(len > 0) {
      //add a file size
      $(elm).eq(i).after("<span> ("+cl.toFixed(2)+" "+sz+")</span>");
    }
  }
  $(function() {
    var elm="a[href$='.pdf'],"+ //only the file types we want
    "a[href$='.doc'],"+
    "a[href$='.ppt'],"+
    "a[href$='.xls'],"+
    "a[href$='.docx'],"+ //don't forget 2007 versions
    "a[href$='.pptx'],"+
    "a[href$='.mht'],"+
    "a[href$='.xlsx']";
    $(elm).each(function(i, e) {
      if (e.hostname && e.hostname == location.hostname) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "HEAD",
          url: $(this).attr("href"),
          complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
          var cl=xhr.getResponseHeader("content-length");
          if(textStatus=="success") {
            var cl=xhr.getResponseHeader("content-length");
            hdrDetails(i, elm, cl); //call the calculation fn
          }else{
            $(elm).eq(i).after("<span> (file not found)</span>");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Starting HTML:

```
<a href="ms0778.01.01.pdf" target="_blank" title="Anti-Defamation League of B’nai B’rith. 1966,1975.">[Digital Archival Object]</a>
```

After existing js:

```
<a href="ms0778.01.01.pdf" target="_blank" title="Anti-Defamation League of B’nai B’rith. 1966,1975.">[Digital Archival Object]</a><span> (1.49 MB)</span>
```

DESIRED affect:

```
<a href="ms0778.01.01.pdf" target="_blank" title="Anti-Defamation League of B’nai B’rith. 1966,1975.">[Digital Archival Object <span>(1.49 MB)</span>]</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this to insert the text just before last character of your link :

```
var $e = $(elm).eq(i);
var t = $e.text();
$e.html(t.slice(0, -1)+"<span> ("+cl.toFixed(2)+" "+sz+")</span>"+t.slice(-1));
```

Comment: +1 The only one of us to see the `]`! But the asymmetry of using `text` to get the content and `html` to set it bothers me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Of course it supposes there is no other tag inside the a element. We could use html in both case but this could lead to bad html. My solution can only remove some elements, not break the link.

Comment: @dystroy Thank you! This almost does it. It turns out a bit funky. Here's what happens: `<a href="ms0778.01.01.pdf" target="_blank" title="Anti-Defamation League of B’nai B’rith. 1966,1975.">]<span> (1.49 MB)</span>[Digital Archival Object</a>`

Comment: @Nathan It seems to work for me : http://jsfiddle.net/UyNEc/ (note that during a few seconds a version where the indexes were bad was visible, maybe you copied my code at that time).

Comment: @dystroy That must have been it, it's working now. THANK YOU!